# How to open RadWindow on JavaScript Confirm Ok Click?

Tags: javascript, radwindow

I have a RadWindow in my page and I want to open the RadWindow on JavaScript Confirm Ok Click.
It is not getting the clientid of the radwindow:

```
function getAddWindowOnConfirm() {
                var proceed = confirm("Click ok to continue");
                if (proceed == true) {
                    var wnd = $find('<%=RadWindow1.ClientID %>');
                if (wnd != null) {
                    wnd.set_title("Add Test");
                }
                var id = 0;
                var frm = "Test.aspx";
                var urlSearchString = frm + "?id=" + id;
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);

                radopen(urlSearchString, "RadWindow1");
                }
                else {
                    //indow.location = "<base target='_parent'>";
                }
            }
```

Comment: A really ambiguous title with only code in the body of your question is not going to get you answers.

Comment: it is getting the id - var id = 0; - it's getting 0 , like you told it to

Comment: No in var wnd its not returning the clientId of the radWindow. Its getting null